# Laravel Blade @foreach : parse error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel, and I cannot find my mistake. I'm sure it's stupid, but the error message it's not really explicit, and I have not found a similar error on the net.

I have this Blade template:

```
@extends('basicTemplateInside')

@section('title')
    ABC
@endsection

@section('content')
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($lines as $line)
        <tr>
          <td> {{ $line->name }} </td>
          <td> {{ $line->creationTimeStamp }} </td>
          <td></td>
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
@endsection
```

and it gives me this error in line 19 [  @foreach ($lines as $line)  ]:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
FatalErrorException in 79b7933d82e3f98a55e82cb71b63543f97265b8b.php line 19: parse error
1. in 79b7933d82e3f98a55e82cb71b63543f97265b8b.php line 19
```

If you think the problem might be in the controller, here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\CableType;


class CableTypesContoller extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        $cableTypes = CableType::all();
        //$data = array('lines'=>$cableTypes,'title'=>'Cable Types');
        //return view('insideTable5wDelSee')->with($data);
        return view('insideTable5wDelSee')->with('lines',$cableTypes);
    }

}
```

The compiled file 79b7933d82e3f98a55e82cb71b63543f97265b8b.php :

```
<?php $__env->startSection('title'); ?>
    ABC
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach($lines as $line): ?>
        <tr>
          <td> <?php echo e( $line->name); ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo e($line->creationTimeStamp); ?> </td>
          <td></td>
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('basicTemplateInside', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

and basicTemplateInside.blade.php :

```
@extends('basicTemplate')

@section('body')
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> ****** </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="content" style="margin-top: 5%;">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
          <h1>@yield('title')</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">


          @yield('content')

        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>

@endsection
```

and basicTemplate.blade.php (if you need the one before, you might need this one too) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>****** - @yield('pageTitle')</title>

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" >

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    @yield('body')

    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/jQuery.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you paste your compiled view file? `79b7933d82e3f98a55e82cb71b63543f97265b8b.php`

Comment: Please show line 19 of `storage/framework/views/79b7933d82e3f98a55e82cb71b63543f97265b8b.php`

Comment: It's quite possible the parse error is in the `basicTemplateInside` layout file, not the one you pasted here.

Comment: Now you can see basicTemplateInside, basicTemplate, and the compiled file. I hope that helps...

Comment: Line 19 of the compiled file is `<td> <?php echo e( $line->name); ?> </td>`.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Try to remove this line and next one from original view. What error you're getting now?

Comment: If I remove everything between foreach and endforeach (including the foreach and endforeach) and replace it with {{ $lines[0]->name }}, it works, I mean, I have no error. If I leave the foreach and I replace everything inside by {{ $lines[0]->name }}, it does not work... So to me, the problem is in the foreach.

Comment: I can even write {{ $lines[0]->name }} {{ $lines[1]->name }}   without the foreach, and I get an output, so, it's not a problem of not having more than one element (if that may happen)

Comment: Hi, can you show the raw result of $cableTypes? I wanted to see the structure of the result. Thanks!

Comment: How do you want me to show it exactly?  Excuse my lack of knowledge, but, do you want me to show a echo($cableTypes) ? @rutherbergonia  That's what I got if so: [{"id":1,"active":1,"creationTimeStamp":"2017-03-05 14:38:24","name":"Radiall 256","pictureURL":"","Users_id":1},{"id":4,"active":1,"creationTimeStamp":"2017-03-05 14:38:51","name":"Radiall 104","pictureURL":"-","Users_id":1}]

Comment: (@RutherBergonia look the comment before. I think I did not write your name right)